# beep in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, speakers

I want to use `beep` (the command line utility), but it isn't working on my Asus laptop, which runs Ubuntu 14.04. I think there's a conflict with that awful wood-block terminal bell sound.

I was able to install it normally with apt-get, and it runs without any errors, but it makes no sound. How can I make it work?

Edit: Things I've tried that haven't worked:

- I've tried removing `pcspkr` from the blacklist from the command line
  and in `blacklist.conf`
- Reinstalling `pulseaudio` and `alsamixer`
- Removing `pulseaudio-module-x11` (apparently this is the module that
  replaces the normal terminal bell with the wood-block sound). I
  didn't think this would do anything anyway, since `module-x11-bell`
  wasn't even loaded in the first place.

If anyone can help me get rid of the wood-block sound and replace it with a normal system beep, that would be awesome.

Comment: I can reproduce that it does not make any sound on my Acer Aspire E5-773G notebook on Ubuntu 16.04 as well, neither in any terminal emulator, nor on a TTY. Maybe our notebooks don't have an internal PC speaker (just the normal built-in speakers which might not respond on this command)? I don't know, just a thought.

Comment: commandline `alsamixer` and check if it has a `beep` option :)

Comment: I don't have a beep option in alsamixer (or at least it's not labeled "beep")

Answer (score 0):

You may not pcspkr module is not loaded into the kernel. 
Try

```
sudo modprobe pcspkr
```

I think Ubuntu default does not load this module.

Comment: This seems to do nothing, even if I reboot. The alsamixer screen doesn't change either.